# Very slow query on mysql table with 35 million rows

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out why a query is so slow on my MySQL database. I've read various content about MySQL performance, various SO questions, but this stays a riddle for me.

1. I am using MySQL 5.6.23-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2. I have a table with roughly 35 million rows.
3. This table is being inserted to about 5 times / second
4. The table looks like this:
   [image]
5. I have indexes on all the columns except for answer_text

The query I'm running is:

```
SELECT answer_id, COUNT(1) 
FROM answers_onsite a 
WHERE a.screen_id=384 
 AND a.timestamp BETWEEN 1462670000000 AND 1463374800000 
GROUP BY a.answer_id
```

this query takes roughly 20-30 seconds, then gives a result set:

[image]

Any insights?

**EDIT**

as asked, my show create table:

```
CREATE TABLE 'answers_onsite' (
  'id' bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'device_id' bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  'survey_id' bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  'answer_set_group' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  'timestamp' bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  'screen_id' bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  'answer_id' bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  'answer_text' text,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
  KEY 'device_id' ('device_id'),
  KEY 'survey_id' ('survey_id'),
  KEY 'answer_set_group' ('answer_set_group'),
  KEY 'timestamp' ('timestamp'),
  KEY 'screen_id' ('screen_id'),
  KEY 'answer_id' ('answer_id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35716605 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Pls add the query's explain output and list all indexes you have on the table. You probably do not have a multi column index that would speed up the query.

Comment: Screenshots are usually a terrible way of showing this information. Can you replace that with the textual content of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for that table?

Comment: updated my question, pasted the create table statement. Also, the indexes are well explained there

Comment: have you tried replaceing between with > and < ? Also, run a analyze table and see if it helps.

Comment: Analyze table will kill my production environment, as I wrote, this table has 35 million rows and is being inserted to multiple times each second

Comment: What about the explain?

Comment: So which of the following answers solved the problem? I'm facing this issue now as well 

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER TABLE answers_onsite ADD key complex_index (screen_id,`timestamp`,answer_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use mysql [Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html) like this :

```
alter table answers_onsite drop primary key;
alter table answers_onsite add primary key (id, timestamp) partition by HASH(id) partitions 500;
```

Running the above may take a while depending on the size of your table.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your WHERE clause:

`WHERE a.screen_id=384 
 AND a.timestamp BETWEEN 1462670000000 AND 1463374800000 
GROUP BY a.answer_id`

I would create a composite index (screen_id, answer_id, timestamp) and run some tests.
You could also try (screen_id, timestamp, answer_id) to see if it performs better.

The BETWEEN clause is known to be slow though, as any range query. So is COUNT on million of rows. I would count once a day and save the result to a 'Stats' table which you can query when you need...obviously if you do not need live data.